# how to have a set number of columns with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

a bit new to jquery I have found this fiddle where I can edit and add both rows and columns I want the user to be able to only edit the number of rows only and have a set number of 4 columns?

https://jsbin.com/dehove/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        Set Rows:<br>
        <input type="text" id="setRows">
        <br>
        Set Columns:<br>
        <input type="text" id="setColumns">

        <button type='button'>Create Table</button>
        <p id = "demo1"></p>
        <p id = "demo2"></p>




    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery

```
    $(function(){ // DOM ready



    $("button").click(function(){

      var setRows    = +$("#setRows").val();
      var setColumns = +$("#setColumns").val();

        var table = "<table>";
        for (var i=0; i<setRows; i++){
            table += "<tr>";
            for (var j = 0; j < setColumns; j++) table += "<td>column</td>";
            table += "</tr>";
        }
        table += "</table>";


        $("p:last").after(table);

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the value of `setColumns` to 4

```
 var setColumns = 4;
```

Also delete the input for the columns
Your full HTML file looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        Set Rows:<br>
        <input type="text" id="setRows">
        <br>


        <button type='button'>Create Table</button>
        <p id = "demo1"></p>
        <p id = "demo2"></p>




    </body>
</html>
```

And This is the javascript

```
    $(function(){ // DOM ready



    $("button").click(function(){

      var setRows    = +$("#setRows").val();
      var setColumns = 4;

        var table = "<table>";
        for (var i=0; i<setRows; i++){
            table += "<tr>";
            for (var j = 0; j < setColumns; j++) table += "<td>column</td>";
            table += "</tr>";
        }
        table += "</table>";


        $("p:last").after(table);

    });


});
```

[This is the js bin](https://jsbin.com/tiritatufo/edit?html,css,js,console,output)
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yep, got this to work! Thanks @andrew! How would I be able to only allow the first row to say 'column' while the other rows are left blank?

Comment: Your welcome! Please consider accepting this answer if it helped

Comment: Sure, how do I do that? :) sorry, new on here as well!

Comment: Click the check under the up arrow

Comment: thanks, done! just a final question, would I be able to only allow the first row to say 'column' while the other rows are left blank?

Comment: Yes, here is the [link](https://jsbin.com/laqozakaku/1/edit?html,css,js,console,outputt). You would change the string below the comment to change the other rows.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, since all the rows are saying column, how can I keep the first row to say column and give the rest of the rows another value instead?

Comment: sorry for late response but here's the [link](https://jsbin.com/fizumotiyu/edit?html,js,output)